# Array insert and shift

Tags: ruby

I have the below array:

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, nil, nil]
```

And I'd like to insert an element `num` into index 2 such that the resulting array is:

```
a = [0, 1, num, 2, 3, 4, nil] # note the size hasn't changed
```

I realize an Array might not be the most suitable data structure for this exercise, but assume that's a requirement.

How can I do this?

### Why?

I'm trying to solve this problem:

> You are given two sorted arrays, A and B, where A has a large enough buffer at the end to hold B. Write a method to merge B into A in sorted order

Here's my code so far:

```
def merge(a, b) # merge b -> a
  pointer = 0 # on a
  while !b.empty? do
    case b.first <=> a[pointer]
    when 0, 1 next
    when -1
      # insert element, shift array to the right
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Do you really need the nils? Describing your exact purpose may help people answer better.

Comment: Edited with details

Comment: Worth noting that this is *not* the optimal solution to the problem I cited. It's better to sort the elements in both a & b to the end of a, with the largest first. That way, the need for shifting is eliminated

Comment: If you sort `a & b`, you lose the information that `a` and `b` are sorted. The most efficient way would be to use an empty `c` array. shifting ist expensive and not needed for the merge sort.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
a.insert(2, num)
```

Not sure if you looking to manually shift the elements, but this should do all of the work for you.

Comment: Yup, but with a `.[0...-1]` chained to retain the size. Thanks